# App Not Setup: Error Facebook

Tags: facebook, coronasdk

I'm well confused with this new Facebook interface with the Sandbox button gone missing in action.

In the middle of developing an App, so I'm in Sandbox mode - Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? is set to NO (i'm only developing)

I'm logged into my iOS device facebook account as the Administrator of the App, I've set up iOS and bundle ID correctly, set the FBID correctly, yet every time I attempt a facebook login from the device I get ...

"App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up the app properly for Facebook Login".

Anyone got any ideas ? And NO I don't want to make the App available to the general public.

Comment: Well does the error message go away if you switch to live mode for a short test?

Comment: It makes no difference

Comment: So this isn’t about sandbox mode at all … so check your login and platform settings.

Comment: Done so, there correct.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with them.  I think the issue arises from I deleted the App then recreated it, the App ID naturally changes, so code was changed to account for that.  But since then failure to login.  Even removed all the provisioning certs and the facebook App itself ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm a muppet.  Forgot to change the copy of the bundle ID in build.settings for Corona to reflect the new FB App ID !!

```
    CFBundleURLTypes = {
    { 
    CFBundleURLSchemes = { "fbXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", }  
    }
```